# How do I turn off the loot message?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've seen this message about 1,000 times:

[image: Screenshot with a popup message highlighted: "Loot in Multiplayer"; "Your loot is your own!"; "In co-op games, each player is rewarded with individual loot from monsters, chests, corpses and any other clickable item in the world."]

Since I've been playing Diablo 3 for literally a week straight, I really don't need to be told how loot works in multiplayer anymore. How do I turn off this annoying pop up?

Comment: Have you checked options? I am sure there is an option to turn tooltips off. I am not home right now, but I am 99% sure there is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Options` > `Gameplay` > `Interface` > Uncheck "Show Tutorials"

[image]